# Table View in Xib file doesn't load custom table view cell properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I have a Xib with a table view in it (I'm using a Xib and not a regular storyboard because I'm inserting the Xib into a UIPageViewController). In the Xib's class, I register a custom table view cell. Though the cell inserts into the table view, it doesn't resize properly based on it's constraints nor does it change the display of the table view.

Here's my xib:
[image]

Here's my custom cell:
[image]

And here's the setup code I have in the view controller that has the table view Xib:class

```
YearbookPageViewController: UIViewController {
    var signatures: [Signature] = []
    var pageNumber: Int = 0

    convenience init(signatures: [Signature], pageNumber: Int) {
        self.init(nibName: "YearbookPageViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.signatures = signatures
        self.pageNumber = pageNumber
    }

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet var pageTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageTableView.delegate = self
        self.pageTableView.dataSource = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SignatureTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.pageTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:  SignatureTableViewCell.identifier)
    }

}
```

When I run the app, this is what it looks like:

[image]

So basically the custom cell is added to the table view from the xib file, but they aren't sized properly even though the cell has constraints on everything? And, the rest of the tableview is still white with table view lines? I'm not sure if the table view isn't responding correctly because it's in a Xib or if I'm missing something that I'm supposed to add.

Would appreciate any pointers or help on how to get things displaying properly!

Comment: Your tableView is displaying default cell size, You must complete the constraints ladder in  your cell, e.g top and bottom constraints must be added.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @UmairAfzal - That helped make the heights of the cells correct. Is there a reason the rest of the table view is still white with lines instead of just being blank with no more cells after the custom ones finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, tableView displays default height of UITableViewCell. If we want custom height, there can be two ways.

**1. Using  heightForRow method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}
```

**2. Using AutoLayout**

In this case, your tableView cell must apply all required constraints that completes a top to bottom constraint ladder, so that autoLayout can calculate the height of cell at RunTime.

For the second problem, you can remove extra separator. by executing following code in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this;

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

for the empty tableView view.